# Creating these constraints in code, advice required

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nslayoutconstraint

So I am having extreme difficulties in understanding how I can create these same constraints that the interface builder so nicely has created for me.

[image: The situation]

[image: Constraints]

I have been reading the document on apple developer site and trying to follow it, but I can't seem to get these work. I am creating a custom view controller that adds a subview and creates those same constraints for that new view when it's pushed in.(The bottom constraint is where the new view is pushed, the top view is ALWAYS the same) I have written this following code but it doesn't seem to work properly(for example when I simulate in-call status bar, the views don't act like on the initial view where IB has created the constraints)

My code:

```
QVViewController * __weak vc1 = (QVViewController*)self.rootViewController2.parentViewController;
UIView *viewToBePushed = tempV.view;
UIView *topContainerView = self.rootViewController1.view;
id bottomLayoutGuide = tempV.bottomLayoutGuide;


[vc1.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[viewToBePushed]-0-|" options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(viewToBePushed)]];
        [vc1.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[topContainerView]-0-[viewToBePushed]" options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(viewToBePushed,topContainerView)]];
        [vc1.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-138-[viewToBePushed]" options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(viewToBePushed)]];
        [vc1.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[viewToBePushed]|" options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(viewToBePushed)]];
        [vc1.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[viewToBePushed]" options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(viewToBePushed)]];
        [vc1.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[bottomLayoutGuide]-0-[viewToBePushed]" options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(viewToBePushed, bottomLayoutGuide)]];
```

Basically

viewToBePushed represents the bottom container in the picture
topContainerView represents the top container in the picture
vc1 is the view where those two container are

I hope I explained the situation clearly enough, if not, ask and I can try to elaborate. I would be really grateful for help as these constraint things are stealing my good night sleep and I very much would want to write easily maintainable code.

So can someone show me how to correctly create those constraints in code.

Comment: When you say the views don't act like they do with the IB constraints, what specifically do you see? BTW, the constraints on the first and fifth lines are redundant, because the fourth line constraint already ties viewToBePushed to both sides of the superview with a 0 length constraint.

Comment: If the IB created constraints do what you need, there is no need to create them in code other than learning. If IB created constraints work, you could create IBOutlet properties to simply adjust them in code where needed.

Comment: @uchuugaka The view in the picture is the root view of my custom splitview controller and the IB creates the constraints for it. When I push a new view in, it rolls over the old one. I want the new view to also have the same constraints so it sizes as it should correctly.

Comment: @rdelmar Well first thing it complains about is that the last constraints doesn't work with some other constraint which I tracked to be the bottom constraint of the bottom container view. Can't two views have constraint related to the bottomLayoutGuide at the same time?

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're trying to accomplish. You have two container views in a view controller. What is embedded in that bottom container view, is it just a view controller or a navigation controller? How are you switching between controllers in that bottom container view?

Comment: @rdelmar There is a normal viewController embedded in the bottom container view, and I have written a system of switching between viewcontrollers on the bottom container, I can post the code that changes the view once I get home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your setup, I think the bottom container view should have whatever constraints you need, but they don't ever need to be changed. When you switch to a new controller embedded in that container view, you can just set constraints to all sides of that container (after viewThatWasPushed is added as a subview)

```
[self.bottomContainerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[viewThatWasPushed]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(viewThatWasPushed)]];
[self.bottomContainerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[viewThatWasPushed]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(viewThatWasPushed)]];
```

self.bottomContainerView is an IBOutlet to theta bottom view.